# How do i update form fields from DB after changing a <select> component

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I have a form which lists a number of stars (stellar objects) upon there is a `<select>` control and two `<inputs>` I am needing advice on populating the two inputs from the DB upon the change of the `<select>` I am using PHP CSS HTML and wondering if I should go down the JS or Ajax route.

Here is the basic form page so far.

```
    <?php
require( '../db_connect.php' );
include( '../inc/tvms_inc.php' );
session_start();
$starsq = "SELECT * FROM ast_stars WHERE constellation=5";
$starsr = mysqli_query( $conn, $starsq );
?>
<!doctype html>
<html data-bs-theme="dark" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        .center-screen {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -50px;
            margin-left: -50px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            border: 3px solid #c0c0c0;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center-screen">
        <h4>Star Selector</h4>
        <form action="process_add.php" method="post">
            <select name="starnumber">STAR No :
        <?php while($star=mysqli_fetch_assoc($starsr)) { ?>
            
            <option value="<?php echo $star['omag']; ?>"><?php echo $star['omag']; ?></option>
            
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
            <br>
            <input name="xcoord" placeholder="X Coord"></input><br>
            <input name="ycoord" placeholder="Y Coord"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I achieve this?

I would need to do a mysqli query on changing the `<select>` and populate the inputs from the results.

Comment: I tried searching for "*php populate input select change*" and found many answers here on SO already, did you review those?  Have you tried any of those approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You can update form fields by calling a js function onchange=myfunction()
and add it to update form fields.

Comment: I know about the onchange event but how would i be able to pass the Mysqli query to retreive the coordinates from the DB

Answer (score 0):

I would go the JS route. Since you're populating all options as select options, I suppose there aren't too many datasets, so there's no need to make users wait for an ajax request to complete.

Here's an example on how to achieve this:

```
<?php
require( '../db_connect.php' );
include( '../inc/tvms_inc.php' );
session_start();
$starsq = "SELECT * FROM ast_stars WHERE constellation=5";
$starsr = mysqli_query( $conn, $starsq );
$options = [];
$coords = [];
while($star=mysqli_fetch_assoc($starsr)) {
    $hash = md5($star['omag']);
    $options[] = "<option value=\"{$hash}\">{$star['omag']}</option>";
    $coords[$hash] = [
        "x" => $star['x'],
        "y" => $star['y'],
    ];
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html data-bs-theme="dark" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
        .center-screen {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-top: -50px;
            margin-left: -50px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            border: 3px solid #c0c0c0;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center-screen">
        <h4>Star Selector</h4>
        <form action="process_add.php" method="post">
            <select name="starnumber" onchange="showCoords(this);">STAR No :
                <?php echo implode(PHP_EOL, $options); ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input name="xcoord" id="xcoord" placeholder="X Coord"></input><br>
            <input name="ycoord" id="ycoord" placeholder="Y Coord"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        const coords = <?= json_encode($coords); ?>;
        function showCoords(select) {
            document.getElementById('xcoord').value = coords[select.value].x;
            document.getElementById('ycoord').value = coords[select.value].y;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You will have to change `$star['x']` and `$star['y']` to whatever field names you are using. I was assuming `x` and `y` since you didn't provide your db schema.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I have muddled through, may be a bit crude but any ideas on cleaning it up would be appreciated, JS is not my 1st language.

for example how would i set the variable 'c' from a php variable?

```
function check_me( ev ) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var e = document.getElementById( "starnumber" );
            var value = e.value;
            var text = e.options[ e.selectedIndex ].text;
            //          alert( "Star Number: " + text );
            var c = 5;
            $.ajax( {
                type: "POST",
                url: "gstarcoords.php",
                data: {
                    'c': c,
                    's': text
                },
                success: function ( response ) {
                    // show response for success
                    let coords = response.split( ',' );
                    let xx = coords[ 0 ];
                    let yy = coords[ 1 ];
                    //alert( 'X = '+xx+'    Y = '+yy );
                    document.getElementById( "xcoord" ).value = xx;
                    document.getElementById( "ycoord" ).value = yy;
                }
            } );
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why would you want to submit the `text` instead of the `value`? As for the variable: My complete answer below shows you how to populate a JS const (or variable for that matter) from PHP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can separate the page that you get and fetch data from the database and then get them with js every time the page load or the select is change.
maybe this solution work for you

Comment: I have separated the php and have an ajax function returning  a response with 890,567 how do I get these into the two input's ajax code below

Comment: ```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function check_me( ev ) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var e = document.getElementById( "starnumber" );
   var value = e.value;
   var text = e.options[ e.selectedIndex ].text;
   alert( "Star Number: " + text );

   var c = 5;
   


   $.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "gstarcoords.php",
     data: { 'c' : c, 's' : text },
    success: function ( response ) {
     alert('FETCH DATA COMPLETE   '+response);
     // show response for success
    }
   } );





  }
 </script>
```

Comment: I mean you have to seperate the fetching data in the other page it means use something like this 
```<?php 
$starsq = "SELECT * FROM ast_stars WHERE constellation=5";
$starsr = mysqli_query( $conn, $starsq );
$options = [];
$coords = [];
while($star=mysqli_fetch_assoc($starsr)) {
    $hash = md5($star['omag']);
    $options[] = "<option value=\"{$hash}\">{$star['omag']}</option>";
    $coords[$hash] = [
        "x" => $star['x'],
        "y" => $star['y'],
    ];
}
?>```
then use an ajax to call this data in the other page